# Ethereum: How to create node and access it?

Tags: python, web3.py

I created address using web3.py and get balance of it.
Result is '0'. It's OK.
But provider URI is 'https://api.myetherapi.com/eth'(indicated [here](https://www.myetherapi.com/))
I think this is live net.
I want to test in testnet.
How can I create ethereum node and use it?
*(Is that I create ethereum node necessary?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. You are a bit confusing about your "test net". Testnet is a network where the chain is completely different from the "normal" one. So accessed from your node or from a remote node won't change anything.

Second, the location of your node does not make the differentiation between testnet and normal net. You could run a geth node on your computer and connect to it, it would be normal net if you don't specify specific parameters. Or you can connect to a remote testnet node.

To run your own node, check the geth documentation.  => https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth

Edit for the comments:

**Whare are nodes?**
I cannot explain completely how ethereum works. not because I don't know but because it would take too much time. But here are the main principles:

People share the exact same "database", they synchronize with each other.
If you want to be part of it, you can use a specific software (like geth) to get the chain. You now are a node. You can just be a node that synchronizes and nothing else, or you can be a miner.

To act on the chain, you need to send transaction connecting to a node. It does not matter where the node is. It can be yours, or an other one like Infura (https://infura.io/) that provides keys to connect to their node(s). Once your transaction has been transfered to the node, it will be broadcast and someone will mine it.

**What is testnet?**
Testnet is a common name to qualify "tests" networks.
Ethereum has 4 main networks:
mainnet: the main network. Where your ether actually has value (in theory)
ropsten: test network. Your ether is worth NOTHING. You can ask to get ether to faucet. It's free. It is used for testing your smart contracts (for example)
rinkeby: also a test net
kovan: also a test net

Some of them have specificities, in particular about the way they work (POW, POS...)

If you are new to ethereum, I STRONGLY RECOMMEND reading documentation like the white paper (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) and, if you want more technical details, the yellow paper: http://yellowpaper.io/

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is right. What I want to know is just 'remote test node'. How to create and connect it?

Comment: I am so sorry. I am new to ethereum, so I don't know about concept of 'node' and 'testnet'. Your answer is greate helpful to me. I'll wait your answering.

Comment: @Mickey102644 I updated my answer